# How to update typescript typings

Tags: typescript-typings

Will somebody please help me understand how to update typings via the typings.json?
When I update certain libraries, their typings become deprecated. This is all well and good, but running typings install --save or any combination of typings install with any of my given libraries throws errors a-la "unable to find angular-protractor", etc.

The problem is that I can't understand how you're supposed to derive the version number. I understand that it is derived from the timestamp of the commit or whatever, but that seems like a terrible way to try to update something as simple as a typing. Particularly since, the only way I've found to be able to upgrade them, is find them and update typings.json manually.

For example:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
        "angular-protractor": "registry:dt/angular-protractor#1.5.0+20160425143459",
    }
}
```

So, version 1.5.0+20160425143459 is deprecated, but I have no idea what the new one is since it won't tell me, and the angular-protractor definition on github in the definitely typed repo doesn't seem to provide any info past the major/minor/patch.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Thanks for any help.